# How to send C++ console params to C# DLL

Tags: c#, c++

I need to send two numbers entered as parameters or requested by C++ console to a library in C#.

Manually the code is:
BSTR thing_to_send = ::SysAllocString(L"10 20");

How can I create a variable of type BSTR using the values of the parameters indicated by the console or by two variables of type integer or string.

I need to concatenate the values using a space between them, for example:

string Num1 = 30;

string Num2 = 40;

string dataToSend = Num1 + " " + Num2;

or

string Num1 = argv[1];

string Num2 = argv[2];

string dataToSend

dataToSend += Num1 + " ";

dataToSend += Num2;

How I can convert dataToSend to BSTR valid variable to send with:

HRESULT hResult = obj->GetTheThing(dataToSend, &returned_thing);?

What I have tried:

In each page that I have reviewed other types of values of origin for the transformation are indicated, with explicit values of chain like being "Cade to convert" but not with the use of variables as it is in this case

The code I need to solve is:

```
BSTR thing_to_send = ::SysAllocString(L"10 20");
BSTR returned_thing;
BimObjectTest_CSharp::_TheClassPtr obj(__uuidof(BimObjectTest_CSharp::TheClass));
HRESULT hResult = obj->GetTheThing(thing_to_send, &returned_thing);
```

the literal L "10 20" must be replaced by the parameters of the console or by two variables requested via the console, note the space between the values!
BSTR thing_to_send should contain, for example, argv[1] + " " + argv[2]!

Comment: BSTR in c++ is really a byte[] terminates with a '\0'.  Strings in c# are two byte objects with a private property which indicates if the character is one or two bytes.  Encoding method will set the private property indicating the number of bytes.  BSTR uses Encoding.UTF8 which makes all the characters one byte.

Comment: I really know what I need, what I have asked is how to achieve it?

Comment: From your question I conclude that you have C# library that takes BSTR arguments and in your C++ client app you want to construct BSTR from command line arguments. Is this correct?
C# libraries usually do not take BSTR arguments, unless they export COM objects, which is of course possible.
Anyway we can reduce your question to "How to construct BSTR from two strings?" or "How to append to BSTR"? Is this correct?

Comment: Google "c++ convert std::string to bstr".  Lotsa hits, many on SO.

Comment: @ devdimi, I am sending parameters from a console in C ++ to a library in C #, if I use a literal like the one indicated in the question, that is, something like L "10 20", the conversion works but if I try it with a string variable , it does not work.

Comment: @Hans Passant, You really think that I have not tried, but as I have indicated, the examples are with literals and not through the use of a string variable as parameter for the conversion

Comment: You don't need one more google hit that isn't helpful to you.  Show what you tried and no doubt somebody will point out the mistake.

Comment: If the parameters to be passed to the C# program are the same parameters in the command line then you do not need to concatenate the separate parameters, the C and C++ runtimes split the parameters but you can call Windows to get the parameters as they exist in the command line.

Comment: Have you considered using C++/CLR? Using C++/CLR you can call GetTheThing nearly the same as if you were doing that in C#.

Comment: You show C++ code but no C# code. In particular, you do not show what data type that C# is taking. You also do not specify whether you have control of the C# source code. I doubt that you must pass a BSTR but you don't show us what C# is expecting. You also do not specify if your C++ program is Unicode; if not then the conversion to Unicode might be why you think you must use a BSTR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function CombineStrings, that combines two _TSTRINGs to BSTR with space between them. There is also a main function that show how to call it with console arguments.

```
BSTR CombineStrings(_TCHAR* arg1, _TCHAR* arg2) {
        long len1 = wcsnlen_s(arg1, 100);
        long len2 = wcsnlen_s(arg2, 100);

        BSTR result = SysAllocStringLen(NULL, len1 + len2 + 1);
        memcpy(result, arg1, len1 * sizeof(OLECHAR));
        memcpy(result + len1, L" ", 1 * sizeof(OLECHAR));
        memcpy(result + len1 + 1, arg2, len2 * sizeof(OLECHAR));

        result[len1 + len2 + 1] = NULL; // contains "firstarg<empty>secondarg"
        return result;
    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        if (argc < 3) {
            // two arguments required.
            return -1;
        }

        BSTR combinedStr = CombineStrings(argv[1], argv[2]);
        BSTR returned_thing;
        HRESULT hResult = obj->GetTheThing(combinedStr, &returned_thing);

        SysFreeString(combinedStr);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: THe line BSTR str1 = SysAllocString(<your first argument here>) show a error if I replace the <your first argument here> with a string variable, this work with literals only

Comment: Your idea is good, I put the code I need to fix, can you check that!

Comment: ok I have capsuled the code to combine the string in a function that can be called with console arguments

Comment: It works perfect, you saved me the weekend, thank you very much